# Convertir un valor string a Date

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot

necesito convertir un valor string el cual tiene el siguiente valor(4/04/2022) a una variable de tipo Date,para haci poder enviar esa variable Date a un Procedimiento almacenado en oracle.

En el codigo estoy intentando convertir el Valor string el cual me llega por el objeto SapsCabPedidoMasivoRequest en la variable PI_FECHA.

Lo que quiero en convertir el valor (4/04/2022) a una variable Date que tenga el mismo valor (4/04/2022)

Espero se me haya podido entender ,gracias.

Codigo =

@Override
public SapsCabPedidoMasivoResponse sapsCabPedidoMasivoResponse(String msjTrx, SapsCabPedidoMasivoRequest request)
throws DBException {

```
    logger.info(msjTrx + Constantes.INICIO_METODO);
    
    String nombreDB = propiedadesExternas.msincdbNombre;
    String owner = propiedadesExternas.msincdbOwner;
    String nombreSP = propiedadesExternas.msincdbSISACTpkg + Constantes.PUNTO
            + propiedadesExternas.msincdbSISACTcabMasivosp;
    
    logger.info(msjTrx + "Consultando a la BD: " + nombreDB);
    logger.info(msjTrx + "OWNER: " + owner);
    logger.info(msjTrx + "STORE PROCEDURE: " + nombreSP);
    
    SapsCabPedidoMasivoResponse response = new SapsCabPedidoMasivoResponse();
    
    try {
        
        logger.info(msjTrx + "Consultando a la DB: " + nombreDB);
        logger.info(msjTrx + "Ejecutando SP: " + nombreSP);
        logger.info(msjTrx + "Parametros SP [Input]:");
        
        Field[] fields = SapsCabPedidoMasivoRequest.class.getDeclaredFields();

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            Field field = request.getClass().getDeclaredField(fields[i].getName());
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = field.get(request);
            logger.info(msjTrx
                    + String.format(Constantes.MOSTRAR_LOG_FORMAT, fields[i].getName().toUpperCase(), value));
        }
        
        Map<String, Object> resultMap = null;
        
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        
Date fecha2;

        Date fecha =  formato.parse(request.getPI_FECHA());
        
        fecha2= new java.util.Date(fecha.getTime()); 
    
    
           
        
        logger.info(msjTrx + "fecha = "+fecha);
        
        logger.info(msjTrx + "fecha2 = "+ fecha2);
        
        
        datasourceMsinc.setLoginTimeout(Integer.parseInt(propiedadesExternas.msincdbSISACTspConexionTimeout));
        
        objJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(this.datasourceMsinc).withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                .withSchemaName(owner).withProcedureName(nombreSP)
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter(Constantes.PI_CODOFICINA, OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter(Constantes.PI_FECHA, OracleTypes.DATE),
                        new SqlOutParameter(Constantes.PO_CUR_PEDPOST, OracleTypes.CURSOR, new ActorMapper4()),
                        new SqlOutParameter(Constantes.PO_CUR_PEDPRE, OracleTypes.CURSOR, new ActorMapper5()),
                        new SqlOutParameter(Constantes.PO_NRO_ERROR, OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlOutParameter(Constantes.PO_DES_ERROR, OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
                        
        objJdbcCall.getJdbcTemplate()
        .setQueryTimeout(Integer.parseInt(propiedadesExternas.msincdbSISACTspejecucionTimeout));
        
        
    
        
        resultMap = objJdbcCall
                .execute(new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue(Constantes.PI_CODOFICINA, request.getPI_CODOFICINA())
                        .addValue(Constantes.PI_FECHA,fecha2));
        
        
        
        response.setPO_NRO_ERROR(resultMap.get(Constantes.PO_NRO_ERROR).toString());
        response.setPO_DES_ERROR(resultMap.get(Constantes.PO_DES_ERROR).toString());
        
        response.setCursorPedPost((List<CursorPedPost>) resultMap.get(Constantes.PO_CUR_PEDPOST));
        response.setCursorPedPre((List<CursorPedPre>) resultMap.get(Constantes.PO_CUR_PEDPRE));
        
        
    } catch (Exception e) {

        this.errorGenerico(e, msjTrx, nombreSP, nombreDB);
    }

    
    return response;
}
```

Dejo los datos que necesita el procedimiento almacenado para funcionar. =
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La manera en la que puedes convertir una cadena a un tipo de dato date en Oracle es usando la función to_date, Ejemplo:

```
to_date('07/04/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Como puedes ver tienes que especificar el formato.
Si quieres saber más visita este link
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php